# App nationality in Play Store while updating from different location

Tags: applications, google-play-store, vpn

For some reasons I have to use VPN for downloading apps from play store. I want to know when I change the IP for example to US and my Play Store change to US. Does it give me different app in US edition?

If yes, when I download with VPN and if I turn off the VPN and back to local Play Store I still can update that app downloaded with VPN now. The confusing thing for me is, if I downloaded an app with VPN using US IP address and update it with my real ip what edition of app I get? Does it still update with the US version of the app?